# NUNIT3 why TestCaseSource is run first and then the SetUp or SetUpFixture

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nunit, nunit-3.0

I do not understand why the data entry reading (TestCaseSource) is executed (SetUp) or (SetUpFixture), before reading the data I need to pass some parameters such as the excel path that I will read and the sheet

code:

```
  [SetUpFixture]
public class before
{
    ManageProperti config = new ManageProperti();

    public void beforeTestFixture()
    {
        config.updateValueAppConfig("excelPath", "Alexia/Tests/Data/Login/Login.xlsx");
        config.updateValueAppConfig("hoja", "Hoja1");
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class LoginOK : TestCase
{

    [Test]
    [TestCaseSource(typeof(ReadExcelCases), "BudgetData")]
    public void LoginOk(String username, String password)
    {
        try
        {............
```

not like that

```
   [TestFixture]
public class LoginOK : TestCase
{
    ManageProperti config = new ManageProperti();

    [SetUp]
    public void before()
    {
        config.updateValueAppConfig("excelPath", "Alexia/Tests/Data/Login/Login.xlsx");
        config.updateValueAppConfig("hoja", "Hoja1");
    }

    [Test]
    [TestCaseSource(typeof(ReadExcelCases), "BudgetData")]
    public void LoginOk(String username, String password)
    {
        try
        {.............
```

I'm reading an excel file, the idea is that each test case is fed from a file

Thanks!!

Comment: There is a relevant discussion in this [github issue](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/141). In summary, running of the test case source is part of the discovery phase where all cases are enumerated, where as various setup methods are part of the execution phase. The authors made the determination that discovery must not depend on execution so no setup methods are called during discovery. This is designed so various UIs can enumerate cases easily. The test case source can be a method so i'm not sure why you can't just do whatever you need to do in that method.

Comment: As one of those developers, @mikez has the correct answer and I can't add much. As he says, just move your config updates to the `TestCaseSource`. You can do anything you want in it, you don't just have to return data.